# Списки в цикле странно себя ведут при добавлении

Tags: python, list, список, append

```
li = [1]
li2= []

for _ in range(2):
    li2.append(li)
    li += [3]
print(spisok)
```

> [[1, 3, 3], [1, 3, 3]]

Если в цикле список li2 добавляет список li в том же цикле,  при этом список li добавляется как-будто прошел весь цикл.  Не понимаю, тогда как добавлять последовательно изменяемый список в цикле

Answer (score 2):

Список хранит ссылки на объекты (на самом деле все переменные хранят ссылки на объекты). Вы в цикле добавляете в список ссылку на один и тот же объект, и в этот же объект добавляете элементы.

Если нужно чтобы в списке были разные объекты, не связанные друг с другом, нужно делать копию объекта перед добавлением:

```
li = [1]
li2= []

for _ in range(2):
    li2.append(li.copy())
    li += [3]

print(li2)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1], [1, 3]]
```

При добавлении объектов большей вложенности также может потребоваться "глубокая" копия:

```
from copy import deepcopy

li = [[1]]
li2= []

for _ in range(2):
    li2.append(deepcopy(li))
    li[0] += [3]

print(li2)
```

Выведет `[[[1]], [[1, 3]]]`, а с обычным копированием (или без копирования) - `[[[1, 3, 3]], [[1, 3, 3]]]`